# Excel Conditional Formatting formula based on the last date of one column for certain criteria in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dax, conditional-formatting

I have a table with Column A being the Criteria and Column B being the Date.
I need help with a conditional formatting formula to highlight the latest date for a all the unique criteria.
See screenshot below of an example, note only the last date should be highlighted for all unique criteria.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nw2Dv.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a conditional formatting formula with:

```
=MAX( ($A$2:$A$10=A2) * $B$2:$B$10 ) = B2
```

where your data are in A2:B10.